# How to trigger a function when a img is full loaded with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I tried something like:

```
$('img').load(function() { /*code*/ });
```

it will work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work as you per your need.

```
$(imageSelector).load(functiont(){ });
```

If you are creating the image dynamically then try this

```
$("<img />").appendTo(document.body).load(functiont(){ }).attr("src", imageSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use $(document).ready(function() { /*code*/ });

$('img') would be for all image tags. Did you try it?

Comment: this img will be generate via javascript

Answer (score 0):

DOM is ready when everything's loaded

use

```
$(function(){
  alert('images are loaded)';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax, however from the jquery api:

"Caveats of the load event when used with images

A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:

It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser

It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before

It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree

Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache"

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/